# Crazy unexpected behavior of grepl

Tags: r, grepl

What explains the following very unexpected behavior of `grepl`?
I am using `grepl` for basic string matching here, and I think the default behavior as illustrated below is dangerous.

```r
> grepl('a','a')
[1] TRUE
> grepl('a ()','a ()')
[1] TRUE
> grepl('a (b)','a (b)')
[1] FALSE
```

Adding `fixed=TRUE` fixes it. The documentation says:

> pattern: character string containing a regular expression (or character string for fixed = TRUE) to be matched in the given character vector.

The average user should get from the message above that the **default usage of grepl is NOT string matching but regular expression matching**, which is not super clear. Someone unaware of regular expressions may not realize the dangers of leaving `fixed` to its default value. I think a warning should be added about this.

Posting here mainly to alert the community about this behavior. It took me a couple of hours of debugging to narrow down the issue I was experiencing in my Shiny app to this function. I would have never thought that grepl could be dangerous like this.

Comment: That is because `()` are special characters in REGEX. the reason why first one is  TRUE is because you have an `a` followed by a space then you capture a null character. Hence its just an a and a space. which means that the a and space is matched thereby returning true. In the second one, it is false since  you have an a followed by space followed by a captured b as the pattered yet you have a then space then opening parancthesis and then b. This is not matched by the pattern

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I knew it had to do with regex but did not know what was happening

Comment: Well, "grep" stands for "global regular expression print."  The documentation clearly labels the "pattern" argument as a "regular expression." I'm not sure how exactly you assumed it was for string matching. The help page does say "pattern matching" and those patterns (not strings) are defined by regular expressions. I'm not really sure anything "dangerous" is happening with the default behavior. It's just that the default behavior is far more powerful. I'm really not sure what would need to be changed to make it more clear.

Comment: @MrFlick is there an R base function dedicated to string matching?

Comment: @MrFlick Of course in principle, you are completely right, and I agree with you. My point is that, in practice, if grepl is used as the default base R string matching function (because there is no other base R function dedicated to this), grepl's parameters should be set to foolproof default values. It should be expected that most users will use grepl for its most basic use case (string matching), and that, if users want to use grepl in "advanced" mode (w/ regexs), they need to set fixed to FALSE. Not the other way around. The documentation on its own does not make a function foolproof.

Answer (score 2):

pattern: `a ()`
Breakdown: An `a` followed by a space   and then a captured null/empty character ie Nothing.

The a and space matches the first part of the string. Thus the WHOLE pattern can be found in the string. RESULTS in   `TRUE`

second part:
pattern: `a (b)`
Breakdown. Literally means `a b` ie `a` then space then `b`. But we capture the `b` hence the parenthesis around `b`.

String has `a (b)`. Since b does not follow the space, the whole pattern cannot be obtained in the string hence `FALSE`